# HTML wrap text around image in div

Tags: html

I have document that looks like this:
[image]

And i want to get the `My text` to  be beside the image, like this:
[image]

Note that I can't use `position: absolute;` because that will make the image position vary between devices.

HTML:

```
<div id="img">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Aloe_vera_%284759242525%29.jpg" height="50%" width="auto" ></img>
</div>
<h1>My text</h1>
```

CSS:

```
div#img{
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
}
```

Comment: What about `float`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to still control the position of the image with relative, you can use float:left on the text and add display:inline to the image.

```
div#img{
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    display: inline;
}
.myText{
    float: left;
}
```

```
<div id="img">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Aloe_vera_%284759242525%29.jpg" height="50%" width="auto" ></img>
</div>
<h1 class="myText">My text</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Float the image to the right. Ex:

```
img {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Or you could make them both `inline-block`

Comment: Well kind of, but i need it to be as close as possible to the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property float:right in main division.
or you can use bootstrap CSS in ordered to preserve it better in small screens

```css
div#img{
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Aloe_vera_%284759242525%29.jpg" height="50%" width="auto" >
</div>
<h1>My text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
div#img{
float: right;
width: 300px;
}
```

instead of:

```
div#img{
position: relative;
left: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox as well.

```css
#img{
    display: flex;
}
#img h1{
    flex:1;
}
#img img{
   flex:1;
   max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
   <h1>My text</h1>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Aloe_vera_%284759242525%29.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix the width of image too, as it will give you a better control on design.

**HTML:**

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Aloe_vera_%284759242525%29.jpg" height="50%" width="50%" align="right" />
<h1>My text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to set the image as a background image and position it to the right.

```css
  #img{
    background-image:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Aloe_vera_%284759242525%29.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: right;  
  }
```

```html
<div id="img" style="height:300px">
  <h1>My text</h1>
</div>
```